# Are exponentials in categorical models of linear logic harmful?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, linear-logic

Categorical models for linear logic with $\otimes$, $1$, $\&$, $\top$, $\oplus$, $0$, and $\multimap$ are typically symmetric monoidal closed categories (for modeling $\otimes$, $1$, and $\multimap$) with products (for modeling $\&$ and $\top$) and coproducts (for modeling $\oplus$ and $0$). Is it harmful to additionally require that such a category has exponentials? Exponentials would model a binary operator $\Rightarrow$ for which proofs of $A \vdash B \Rightarrow C$ correspond to proofs of $A \mathbin\& B \vdash C$. Are there sensible categorical models for linear logic that have exponentials, or does the introduction of exponentials make the structure collapse?

Comment: You may be interested in Bunched Implication (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunched_logic), which is an extension of (intuitionistic) linear logic with exactly this connective $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it does not make the structure collapse. For example consider the category of small categories $\mathbf{Cat}$ --- it is clearly complete and cocomplete cartesian closed category, and moreover it has another closed monoidal structure induced by the "funny tensor" and linear exponents $\mathbb{C} \multimap \mathbb{D}$ given by the category of functors $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ together with (unnatural) transformations (i.e. "natural transformations" without "naturality" requirement).

Much more is true. Every (small) monoidal category $\langle \mathbb{V}, \otimes, I\rangle$ fully embeds into complete and cocomplete cartesian closed and monoidal closed category. The embedding is given by the usual Yoneda functor $y \colon \mathbb{V} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{V}^{op}}$ and the monoidal closed structure is inherited via the Day convolution:
$$(F \otimes G)(X) = \int^{A, B \in \mathbb{V}} F(A) \times G(B) \times \hom(X, A \otimes B)$$
$$(F \overset{L}\multimap G)(X) = \int_{A, B \in \mathbb{V}} G(A)^{F(B) \times \hom(A, X \otimes B)}$$
$$(F \overset{R}\multimap G)(X) = \int_{A, B \in \mathbb{V}} G(A)^{F(B) \times \hom(A, B \otimes X)}$$
where $\overset{L}\multimap$ is the left linear exponent and $\overset{R}\multimap$ is the right linear exponent (which are isomorphic precisely when the tensor $\otimes$ in $\mathbb{V}$ is symmetric).
Moreover, it is easy to verify that Yoneda functor preserves the monoidal closed structures. Therefore, in some sense, every monoidal category can be (co)completed to a cartesian closed category with coproducts.

Answer (score 8):

Michal already answered the question where we consider *intuitionistic* multiplicative linear logic, without an involutive linear negation; there are many such models where we can have a symmetric monoidal closed structure concurrent with a cartesian closed structure on a category. Another easy example (in fact a special case of one of his constructions) is the topos of $G$-sets where $G$ is an abelian group, made into a symmetric monoidal closed category by using the Day convolution.

I'd like to supplement his answer by mentioning that if you *do* demand an involutive negation as well (i.e., work with classical multiplicative linear logic), which we categorically model using $\ast$-autonomous categories, then we do get a collapse: every such model is posetal. More is true: a cartesian closed category $C$ that is self-dual must be a poset; notice that a classical linear negation gives a self-duality, i.e., an equivalence

$$\neg: C^{op} \stackrel{\cong}{\to} C.$$

This is because the initial object in a cartesian closed category is *strict*, i.e., for any object $X$, if there is a morphism $X \to 0$, then $X \cong 0$. Given that fact, consider morphisms $1 \to (A \Rightarrow B)$. Then, letting $(-)^\ast$ be the self-duality functor, these are in bijective correspondence with morphisms

$$(A \Rightarrow B)^\ast \to 0$$

and if such a morphism exists, then $(A \Rightarrow B)^\ast \cong 0$ by strictness. In particular, there is at most one morphism $(A \Rightarrow B)^\ast \to 0$, and therefore at most one morphism $1 \to A \Rightarrow B$, and hence at most one morphism $A \to B$ for any two objects $A$, $B$.